# Show input cursor in a non-focused RichTextBox

Tags: c#, winforms, cursor, richtextbox

Can I show input cursor in a non-focused RichTextBox?

In my project, I have a RichTextBox and a ListView control. The focus should be on ListView control. I could handle the KeyPress and KeyDown events of ListView and re-directed to RichTextBox to enable typing. But how can I show cursor on RichTextBox.

RichTextBox.focus() cann't be called. The focus must be in ListViewControl (like combobox ). Any Idea....?